# Angular highcharts problem showing week number

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am running into a problem with highcharts in my Angular application, that i simple can´t resolve.

I'm trying to show the week number on the xAxis with the type: 'datetime' as shown below. I found this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/global/dateformats) thats should solve the problem, but when iam trying to use this in my code i will get this error `Cannot assign to 'dateFormats' because it is a constant or a read-only property.` At the bottom of this description I have included the dateFormats description, shouldn't it be possible to do this?

What am I overlooking here :)

**ERROR OCCURS ON LINE 1 IN THE FOLLOWING CODE:**

```
    Highcharts.dateFormats = {
        W: function (timestamp) {
            console.log('timestamp', timestamp);
            return 45;
        }
    };

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        xAxis = {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                format: '{value:Week %W/%Y}'
            },
            minTickInterval: 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7,
            minRange: 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7
        };
    });
```

**FROM HIGHCHARTS FILE**

```
/**
 * A hook for defining additional date format specifiers. New specifiers are defined as key-value pairs by using the
 * specifier as key, and a function which takes the timestamp as value. This function returns the formatted portion
 * of the date.
 */
dateFormats: DateFormatSpecifiers;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a [fix](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9920) added to Highcharts version 7.1.0 the `Highcharts.dateFormats` is initialized as an empty object, so you still cannot override it, but you are allowed to freely add items to it. The items need to be of `Highcharts.TimeFormatCallbackFunction` type, where `type TimeFormatCallbackFunction = (timestamp: number) => string`.

tl;dr: Below code works fine:

```
    Highcharts.dateFormats.W = function (timestamp) {
        console.log('timestamp', timestamp);
        return '45'; // must return string
    };
```

Comment: As the demo caused the confusion it should be fixed soon: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11497

Comment: Thanks for the help @Kacper Madej, it worked like a charm :) 

Unfortunately, I now run into the same problem as mentioned in issue [#9920](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9920), where the Highcharts.dateFormats is undefined. Is there a fix for this too or is it the hard way where i need to update the whole application to use Highcharts > 7

Comment: @mlund86 You should be able to do some casting to `any` or extend TS definitions depending on which exactly version of Highcharts are you using and what is the source of the TS definitions. I could check how this could be resolved if you could share the info about used versions for both.